# Adjust Height of Map in Divi

Tags: css, wordpress

Was hoping to increase the height of the google map module in Divi but my CSS code is not working and do not understand why.  I am pasting the following code within Advanced > Custom CSS > Main Element of the Map Module

```
.et_pb_map {
     height: 440px;
}
```

Any suggestions would be very useful!

Comment: can u share a link to the page ?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute Map for Divi Theme

1. Add the following CSS in the Row Settings/ Custom CSS/ Column "1" Main Element (column number is where you will put the map):

```css
    position:relative;
```

2. Add a Class to Map Module. In this example the CSS Class is absolute_map
   Add the following CSS in the Custom CSS box:

```css
.absolute_map .et_pb_map {
    position: absolute;
    overflow:visible;
    height: 100%; 
}
```

3. Be happy!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `padding` instead of an explicit increase of `height`.

```
#map ,#map .et_pb_map {padding-bottom: 56.25%}
```

*You might have to adjust the selector. Usually `#map` is enough though.*

and adjust the padding percentage to modify the aspect ratio. This is responsive.

The reason why this might work is because **padding creates more space for the background** - map in the case of this iframe - **to be painted** thus expanding it. 
[Read more on this here](https://www.labnol.org/internet/embed-responsive-google-maps/28333/)

[**Working demo on JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz0rfu6g/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're customizing through that section (Advanced > Custom CSS > Main Element) of the Divi Builder, just add the property declaration not the entire CSS rule.

```
 height: 440px;
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to add css class in the advanced > custom css. just add the property value 440px.

Answer (score 0):

use !important for overnight css

```
.et_pb_map {
     height: 440px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add !important to your css

```
.et_pb_map {
     height: 440px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

**Please use your google API key here in this js file.**

If you wanted to increased/decreased height of map then do changes in **#div_gmap**.

```css
      #div_gmap {
        height: 440px;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
<div id="div_gmap"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('div_gmap'), {
          center: {lat: 22.3039, lng: 70.8022},
          zoom: 12
        });
      }
    </script>
```

**If this thing is not working well then might need to check some of the css or any other framework causing this issue.**

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test out why the css dimension code doesnt work is to use chrome dev tool.

Press `Shift+ Ctrl + I` (or `cmd + alt + I` if you are safari user) and open up the web dev tool bar. Go to the **Elements** section and you will see styles controller. In the styles controller, you click on the elements you wanna check on the DOM side, in your case, it's probably `<div class="et_pb_map">...</div>`, or you can press ctrl+f to search `et_pb_map`.

After you have done that, you can go to the box viewer  in the style tab and see why it doesnt work out.

I would say sometimes if you use padding/margin and didnt set overflow property well, it will crop out your elements. Or maybe your class is being overlapped by other class. You can use embed style to override that `<div class="et_pb_map" style="...">...</div>`, or simply put your class as the last class in the class attributes.

[Example on using chrome web dev tool bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiyQO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS and paste this code

```
.et_pb_map iframe {height: 400px !important; }
```

This will help you [Check this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4792sr0/)

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution that worked for me. Assign a class to your map module i.e. `.map-height` and target it like this:

```
.map-height .et_pb_map {
    overflow:visible;
    height: 500px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is:

1. Go to Divi Theme Options
2. Scroll down to Custom CSS
3. Enter `.et_pb_map {height:500px;}`
4. Click Save Changes (the map will now change to 500px height)